# Weird random data being sent from Arduino to Processing

Tags: serial-port, processing, arduino

I'm trying to read data from a photocell resistor and my [Arduino Diecimila](https://docs.arduino.cc/retired/boards/arduino-diecimila) and then graph it in real-time with [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29).

It should be painfully simple; but it’s growing into a little bit of a nightmare for me.

The code I'm running on my Arduino:

```java
int photoPin;

void setup(){

  photoPin = 0;
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){

  int val = int(map(analogRead(photoPin), 0, 1023, 0, 254));
  Serial.println(val); // Sending data over Serial
}
```

The code I'm running in Processing:

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial photocell;

int[] yvals;

void setup(){

  size(300, 150);
  photocell = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
  photocell.bufferUntil(10);
  yvals = new int[width];
}

void draw(){

  background(0);
  for( int i = 1; i < width; i++ ){
    yvals[i - 1] = yvals[i];
  }

  if(photocell.available() > 0){
    yvals[width - 1] = photocell.read();
  }

  for(int i = 1; i < width; i++){
    stroke(#ff0000);
    line(i, yvals[i], i, height);
  }
  println(photocell.read()); // For debugging
}
```

I've tested both bits of code separately, and I know that they work. It's only when I try to have the input from the Arduino going to Processing that the problems start.

When I view the data in Arduino's "Serial Monitor", I get a nice constant flow of data that seems to look valid.

But when I read that same data through Processing, I get a repeating pattern of random values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transmit that data with the Plotly Arduino API, which along with the documentation and setup is available [here](http://plot.ly/api/arduino). Basic idea: you can continuously stream data from your Arduino, or transmit a single chunk.

Then, if you want to embed it into a site, you'll want to grab the URL and use this snippet:

```html
<iframe id="igraph" 
        src="https://plot.ly/~abhishek.mitra.963/1/400/250/" 
        width="400" 
        height="250" 
        seamless="seamless" 
        scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

You can change the width/height dimensions in that snippet. Note: you need to swap in your own URL there to get it stream through.

[Here's an example of how it looks to stream Arduino data](http://plot.ly/%7Eflann321/9/)

[image]

Full disclosure: I work for Plotly.

Answer (score 4):

After a closer look at the resources at hand, I realized that the problem had already been solved for me by the folks over at http://arduino.cc

> http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Graph

Oh how much time I could have saved if I had seen that earlier.

Comment: What specifically was it?